# Some trouble getting my BST to connect in a recursive function

Tags: c++

I need to make a BST that loads information about converting between English and Morse. The idea in this insertnode function is to recursively go down the BST (left is less than in ASCII, right is more) and find the correct spot for the English letter. I'm doing fine going down the tree and finding the right spot, and I create the node correctly in the scope of main, but for whatever reason the left & right continue to be nullptr after the assignment.

I've tried changing the amount of pointers, using references, I can't seem to find out what the issues is.

```
int main(void)
{
ifstream morse; // The file with the translations
ifstream translate; // The file with what needs to be translated
morse.open("morse.txt");
translate.open("convert.txt");

// 1st order of business is to fill the tree from "morse" file, but first I need to declare our tree with the first char.
char letter;
string sound;

if (morse)
{
    morse.get(letter);
    getline(morse, sound); // will be \n
    getline(morse, sound);

    tree<char, string> morsetree(letter, sound); // now we have our tree with a root

    while (morse)
    {
        morse.get(letter);                // grab the english letter
        getline(morse, sound);            // grab the \n
        getline(morse, sound);            // grab the morse translation

        morsetree.insertnode(letter, sound, morsetree.getroot());
    }

    // table is now collected.
    morsetree.printtree(morsetree.getroot());

}

return 0;
}

template<class english, class morse>
treenode<english, morse> *makenode(english newletter, morse newsound) 
//out here for scope
{
    return new treenode<english, morse>(newletter, newsound);
}
```

Above is context for the main & newnode function. Below is the function that is giving me trouble.

```
template<class english, class morse>
void tree<english, morse>::insertnode(english newletter, morse newsound, 
treenode<english, morse> *current) //START WITH ROOT
{
    //also need to think about the fact that english has upcase/lowcase while morse doesn't. Maybe implement that when searching the tree

/*
How this works: I need to make sure that the node goes into the exact place that it is supposed to be. my morse.txt is decently randomized so I shouldn't need
to worry about balancing it. all nodes will be inserted at the bottom of the tree, nothing in the middle. If the letter is less then go to the left, bigger go to the right.
Keep going until it finds a nullptr in which case the newletter has found it's position. This is done recursively.
*/

if (current == nullptr)
{
    current = makenode(newletter, newsound);
}

if (newletter < current->getletter())
{
    return insertnode(newletter, newsound, current->getleft());
}

if (newletter > current->getletter())
{
    return insertnode(newletter, newsound, current->getright());
}

//if none of these the letters already been put into the data. This shouldn't happen though unless I messed up morse.txt
}
```

Below is the code in getleft()

```
template<class english, class morse>
treenode<english, morse> *treenode<english, morse>::getleft()
{
    return left;
}
```

I'll also include the full treenode class for more context.

```
template<class english, class morse> //these are the two template 
//variables being used, one for the english char and 1 for translated morse string.
class treenode
{
public:
treenode(english, morse);

english getletter();
morse getsound();
treenode *getleft();  //returns a pointer to the address of left
treenode *getright();

void setletter(english newletter);
void setsound(morse newsound);
void setleft(treenode *newleft);
void setright(treenode *newright);


private:
english letter;
morse sound;
treenode<english, morse> *left;
treenode<english, morse> *right;
};
```

Comment: `void tree<english, morse>::insertnode(english newletter, morse newsound, 
treenode<english, morse> *current)`  -- Just to let you know, the value of `current` at the caller will not change when the function returns, since `current` is passed by value.

Comment: Do you think you can expand on that a bit? Sorry I just thought that since its *Current in the declaration that would mean that I am passing it by reference.

Comment: [Please look at this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6c9ea5ac7d4a0917).  If this is what you're experiencing, then do a search for how to fix this issue.

Comment: What do ```getleft()``` and ```getright()``` return?

Comment: They return a pointer to the left or right child node. I will edit the post with their code, thanks for asking